# $T=U\Sigma V^T$ is the SVD of T. Given $\Sigma$ find T, U and V.

Tags: linear-algebra

$T=U\Sigma V^T$ is the SVD of T.

$$\Sigma=\pmatrix{11.83&0\\0&0\\0&0}$$

The last two columns of $U$ are $[0.949,0,0.316]^T$ and $[-0.894,0.447,0]^T$

The first column of $V$ is $[0.316,0.949]^T$

a) what are the remaining values in $U$ and $V$?

b) identify the four fundamental subspaces of T.

I know that $\lambda_1=11.83$ and $\lambda_2=0$ (most likely) from $\Sigma$.

The first $r$ columns of $U=C(T)$ and the last $m-r$ columns of $U=n(T^T)$

The first $r$ columns of $V=C(T^T)$ and the last $n-r$ columns of $V=n(T)$.

Also, $$T=U\Sigma V^T$$
$$TV=U\Sigma$$
$$U=AV\Sigma^{-1}$$

How can I use these relationships to find $T$, and the remaining values of $U$ and $V$?  Any help is greatly appreciated.  :)

Comment: Hint: U and V or orthonormal matrices.

Comment: Shouldn't $V$ be $2 \times 2$?

Comment: @Orangutango~ I also know that $T$ is 3x2, $U$ is 3x3 and $V$ is 2x2.  And $U^TU=I$ and $V^TV=I$.  I'm still not seeing something.  I put variables in $U$ to fill the columns and $U\Sigma$ to get an intermediate matrix, $A$.  Then $A*V^T$ to get $T$.  Which turned out to be $$T=\pmatrix{3.73U_{11}&11.2267U_{11}\\3.73U_{21}&11.2267U_{21}\\3.73U_{31}&11.2267U_{31}}$$

Comment: @copper.hat~ yes.

Comment: I second @Amzoti's confusion...

Comment: @Amzoti and copper.hat~ I made the same typo that the prof did.  Sorry!  When I saw the original question I was confused also.  He then fixed it and so did I. I also asked if he wanted actual numerical values or just variables for $T$, $U$ and $V$.  He wants numerical values.....

Comment: @Lanae: Are you sure you write the values of $U$ correctly? They look suspicious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose columns of $U$ are $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$. You know that $u_3$ has to be orthogonal to $u_1$ and $u_2$, and its norm has to be $1$, so there are two possibilities: $u_3 = \pm u_1 \times u_2$, where $\times$ is the cross product in $\mathbb R^3$.

For $V$, the problem is slightly easier. Suppose $v_1$ and $v_2$ are columns of $V$. There are also two possibilities: $v_2 = \pm\begin{pmatrix}v_{1y}\\-v_{1x}\end{pmatrix}$, where $v_{1x}$ and $v_{1y}$ are components of $v_1$.

Despite four choices for $U$ and $V$, we see that
\begin{align*}
U\Sigma V^T & =
\begin{pmatrix}
\vert & \vert & \vert\\
u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \\
\vert & \vert & \vert
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0\\
0 & \lambda_2 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
- \ v_1^T -\\
- \ v_2^T -
\end{pmatrix} \\
& =
\begin{pmatrix}
\vert & \vert\\
\lambda_1u_1 & \lambda_2 u_2\\
\vert & \vert
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
- \ v_1^T -\\
- \ v_2^T -
\end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
We see here that the choice of $u_3$ is actually not important in the product. Also, because $\lambda_2 = 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
U\Sigma V^T & =
\begin{pmatrix}
\vert & \vert\\
\lambda_1u_1 & 0\\
\vert & \vert
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
- \ v_1^T -\\
- \ v_2^T -
\end{pmatrix} \\
& = \lambda_1u_1v_1^T.
\end{align*}
This is your original matrix $T$. It is now easy to see that

- $\text{image}(T) = \langle u_1 \rangle \subseteq \mathbb R^3$
- $\ker(T) = \langle u_2, u_3 \rangle \subseteq \mathbb R^3$
- $\text{image}(T^T) = \langle v_1 \rangle \subseteq \mathbb R^2$
- $\ker(T^T) = \langle v_2 \rangle \subseteq \mathbb R^2$

These answers do not depend on the choice of $u_3$ and $v_2$.

By the way, as Amzoti pointed out, the given values for $u_1$ and $u_2$ are wrong. $u_1$ and $u_2$ are supposed to be orthogonal.

Comment: @Amzoti and Tunococ~  These are the values that the prof gave us $$U=\pmatrix{u_{11}&0.949&-0.894\\u_{21}&0&0.447\\u_{31}&0.316&0}$$ and $$V=\pmatrix{0.316&0.949\\v_{21}&v_{22}}$$

Comment: @Lanae You might want to go back to your prof and ask him/her again.